# "Serial does not name a type error"

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I m getting serial does not name a type error, expected declaration before '}' token line 69

```
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;
const int buzzer = 11;
const int ledPin = 13;

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
int safetyDistance;

void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
}

void loop() {
// Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

// Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  safetyDistance = distance;
  if (safetyDistance <= 5) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

    tone(buzzer, 1000);
    delay(100);
    noTone(buzzer);
    delay(100);
  }

  else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  if (safetyDistance > 5 && safetyDistance <= 10) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

    tone(buzzer, 3000);
    delay(3000);
    noTone(buzzer);
    delay(3000);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  }
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);

}
```

Comment: I formatted your code and now you can see that you have a redundant } before the line with error report

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (safetyDistance > 5 && safetyDistance <= 10) {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

    tone(buzzer, 3000);
    delay(3000);
    noTone(buzzer);
    delay(3000);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
  }                           //<--
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);

}
```

There is a duplicate `}` after the `else` clause is closed. Remove it and your code will compile.

Comment: is this worth an Answer?

Comment: @Juraj Because it answers the question, yes. Even beginner questions deserve to be answered. We have to be more inclusive, as I read in https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/.

Comment: Maximilian, I somehow don't like that I formatted the code in question to show the problem and you write an answer equivalent to my comment

Comment: @Juraj that's true and good that you formatted the question 3 hours ago, but questions are still to be answered in answers and not in comments. And since the question does not really allow for any different answer but this, we also have identical answers